# Skip Filter on particular Action when action filter is registered globally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i'hv written my own action filter and registered in global.asax file, now my problem is how do i skip
this filter for specific actions, i thought about this by creating a custom attribute for e.g `DontValidate`
and place it over the action for which i want to skip the validation, and in my action filter code i'll put a condition that if the action contains
`DontValidate` attribute then skip the validation. So currently i'm not getting how to
implement it:

below code is my validation action filter

```
   public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Method.ToString() == "OPTIONS") return;
            //bool dontValidate =  context.ActionDescriptor. // here im stuck how to do
            var modelState = context.ModelState;
            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                JsonValue errors = new JsonObject();
                foreach (var key in modelState.Keys)
                {
                    // some stuff
                }

                context.Response  = context.Request.CreateResponse<JsonValue>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could get the list of attributes that were used to decorate the controller action from the `ActionDescriptor` property of the context:

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<DontValidateAttribute>().Any())
        {
            // The controller action is decorated with the [DontValidate]
            // custom attribute => don't do anything.
            return;
        }

        if (context.Request.Method.ToString() == "OPTIONS") return;
        var modelState = context.ModelState;
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            JsonValue errors = new JsonObject();
            foreach (var key in modelState.Keys)
            {
                // some stuff
            }

            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse<JsonValue>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
        }
    }
}
```