# Is it possible to override only one authorization filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've got a situation where I use multiple authorization filters to enforce different conditions independent of one another:

```
<UserLevelCanAccessThings>
<UserHasPaidForThings>
Partial Public Class ThingsController
    Inherits Controller

    Function EditThing() As ActionResult
        ...
        Return View()
    End Function

    <OverrideUserIsPaid>
    Function PayToUnlockThings() As ActionResult
        ...
        Return View()
    End Function

End Class
```

Now I've got a situation where I need to have an action bypass *only one* of the filters. For instance, suppose you're allowed to access this controller to work with `Things` if you've achieved a high enough level (first filter) and you've then paid for that access (second filter).

The Pay method needs to enforce the first condition but NOT the second, because I don't want to block the user from paying because he's not paid when he's **trying** to pay!

(I know I could move the Pay method somewhere else, but in my actual situation this isn't desirable. This is just an example to illustrate what I'm asking.)

A global `OverrideAuthorization` attribute turns off ALL authorization, but I need to be more selective about it. How can I do that?

Comment: You might check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270190/how-does-one-get-a-list-of-authorization-filters-that-have-been-applied-to-a-par but it sounds like what you are wanting to do should probably be designed in a different way. Perhaps claims or some other role or permissions paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12891365/349974) by [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov), I did this:

```
Public Class OverrideUserIsPaidAttribute
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
        'no op
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class UserIsPaidAttribute
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
        'get all other filters attached to this action, controller, or globally
        Dim otherFilters = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(True).AsEnumerable '.Where(Function(x) TypeOf x Is IAuthorizationFilter And Not TypeOf x Is OverridePlayerIsPaidAttribute).AsEnumerable(Of IAuthorizationFilter)()
        otherFilters = otherFilters.Union(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(True))
        otherFilters = otherFilters.Union(GlobalFilters.Filters.Select(Function(x) x.Instance))

        'if any of them is an override, bail out before validating
        If otherFilters.OfType(Of UserIsPaidAttribute).Count > 0 Then Return

        'regular validation here
    End Sub
```

Basically, it enhances the `UserIsPaid` authorization to check the attributes of the action, the controller, and global filters to see if there is an override specified, and, if so, simply doesn't do its own authorization. This seems clean enough to me, but I'm open to suggestions.